# Is it possible to get power from an electric motor using wireless?

Tags: power, wireless-charging

I have an electric motor (see description below.) At the same time I  have a micro-controller attached to it which consumes (0.3W-0.4W) powered by a USB port.

I'm wondering if it's possible to power this micro-controller using a wireless charger system (like wireless chargee.)

Does this motor produce a magnetic field to use as a wireless charger?

Hope my idea is clear.

```
Power Rating    7.5 kW
Efficiency Class    IE2
AC Motor Type   Induction
Supply Voltage  400 V, 690 V
Phase   3
Output Speed    1465 rpm
Number of Poles 4
Mounting Type   Foot
Shaft Diameter  38mm
Shaft Length    80mm
Width   256mm
Length  535.5mm
Maximum Output Torque   49 Nm
Current Rating  14.7 A
Depth   262mm
Series  1LE1
Dimensions  535.5 x 256 x 262 mm
Rotation    Reversible
```

Comment: In theory yes, every instrument under power emits an electric field that can be picked up. However, engines are typically designed to minimize this field, because it's unwanted and causes disturbances to nearby electronics. You need very specific electronics to measure the electric field and the frequencies with the maximum amplitude and then you need to construct an antenna that can pick that up with enough current. It's doable, but it's very difficult.

Comment: Engine? I think you mean **electric motor**. In a properly designed electric motor, the magnetic field stays mostly **inside the motor** so there isn't going to be enough magnetic flux to power that micro-controller.

Comment: It would be feasible to extract 0.4W from current transformer(s) on the motor power wires. But it would only work while the motor was powered.

Comment: Mutual coupling increases with closer proximity but frequency vs impedance depends on mutual impedance to load ratio, so unlikely without RF resonance as low f demands huge inductance

Answer (score 1):

> Does this motor produce a magnetic field to use as a wireless charger?

No. The magnetic field it produces is almost completely contained inside the motor casing. Some leakage may be detectable with sensitive instruments, but not nearly enough to power an MCU board through its USB port.

A split-core [current transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_transformer#Function) placed around one of the motor wires might produce enough power, but only if the motor is powered and drawing sufficient current.